# Power BI, filter taking into account multiple columns

Tags: powerbi

I would like to filter a visual based on the combined value of two columns. In this case I have two of my columns, valueA and valueB, and I would like the row to appear on my visual when either of the two values is greater than 1.
In order to achieve this at the moment I create a custom column with the maximum of both values and then filter on this new column but I would be curious to know if there is a direct way to define the filter taking into account the value of multiple columns without having to add a column to the query each time.

Comment: It looks like your solution currently is the only way to achieve what you want. Not sure if this helps, but once your calculated field is added to the visual filter, you can hide it from the table (which will hide in the report view mode).

Answer (score 0):

You could created a calculated column using DAX like this:

```
greaterThan1 = IF(Table1[ValueA]>=1,TRUE(),if(Table1[ValueB]>=1,TRUE(),FALSE()))
```

Then you would just filter where greaterThan1 = true.

Comment: Creating a new column is what I have been doing so far.